# use i18n-node in server-side express application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, internationalization, i18n-node

I can't figure out how I should use i18n-node module inside my application.

Within views, for static texts, it's easy, it works perfectly but...

Here is my problem :

Sometimes I have to set some error messages or something else, e.g :

```
req.flash('message', __('Unknown user %s', login));
```

Then I'll have to send this message to my views, e.g :

```
res.render('myview', {message: req.flash('message')});
```

But first, my message `"Unknown user %s"` will only be set in the default language json file, and then even if I put `"Unknown user %s": "Something in the client language"` in the client language json file, it will still display `"Unknown user myUserLogin"`.

Does someone have a good working example to share ?

Edit: And because, there is a variable in the translated string, I can't just do that :

```
res.render('myview', {message: __(req.flash('message'))});
```

because it will set `"Unknown user myUserLogin"` in the client language json file, instead of `"Unknown user %s"`...

Comment: I'm a bit confused when you mentioned about the output of the client language file being `"Uknown user myUserLogin"`. I'm going to assume that you are saying the output is still the default language instead of the client's language. What happens when you override the locale? 
ie: 

`__({phrase: 'Unknown user {{user}}, locale: 'fr'}, { user: 'Marcus' });`

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is kind of old, but I ran into the same issue and found a solution.

Since your using the `flash` method from the `req` object, you should also use the `__` method available in the same object:

```
req.flash('message', req.__('Unknown user %s', login));
```

This way it's gonna be translated using the current locale of the request.